# Excel VBA Workbook_Open does not work when Excel is already open

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to automate VBA run with its file opening from command line as below:

```
cmd.exe /C set MacroName=MyMacro \& EXCEL.EXE C:\\_documents\\Book2.xlsm
```

The VBA scripts and files are as follows:

Book2.xlsm/Module1

```
Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "MyMacro is running..."
End Sub
```

Book2.xlsm/ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strMacroName As String
    strMacroName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("MacroName")
    If strMacroName <> "" Then Run strMacroName
End Sub
```

Now, the above cmd command does work, expectedly notifies me with the MsgBox, when Excel is not open. But it does not work when Excel is already being open with other project/file(s).

How can I make this work?

Comment: What happens when you put say `Msgbox Worbook Open Executed` in `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`? I just checked, in both scenarios, I got a message box.

Comment: I tried that, and worked. This is totally my bad that I didn't try that simple test. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the final verdict? You got it sorted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when you launch an Excel file in the already open Excel instance passing environment variables through cmd.exe or command line does not work correctly for some reason, rather than as a VBA-side problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question and add this information there. Finally delete this answer :)

Comment: I think this answers to the question here. I assume you may misunderstood that because I included " I appreciate that if someone would help to solve my wondering" clause, but the clause is not for the question but totally unrelated to the topic of VBA. I think I'd rather better open a new post on SO or Github issue for this.